# Is there a way to "bind" a Rails partial view to the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

What I want to do is to do some init coding in the controller before showing the contents of the partial view.

For example, if the partial view is passed an ID of the object, it would be wise to get the object itself and then send it to the view.

You can easily do it with ASP.NET MVC. However in Rails code like

```
def some_partial_view
  @obj = Obj.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

Doesn't work.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

what you've pasted should work.. how do you know it doesn't?

---

**EDIT**
basically you wouldn't render a partial from your controller but inside another view. by passing `:locals` you gain access to specific vars:

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :obj => @obj } %>
```

and in your partial:

```
<%= obj %>
```

Comment: Because when I pass an instance @variable, the partial view doesn't "see" it.

Comment: If so, it sucks. I'd prefer to do partial specific stuff in the controller, no in the parent view. (Like in ASP.NET MVC)

Comment: what do you mean by "partial specific stuff"? you can prepare @obj inside your controller and pass it from the rendered view to the used partial. if you're loading several partials and manipulate the same @obj differently in each partial you'd probably use a `helper`

Comment: And what if I use a loop to make a table of partials? A good example would be blog posts.

Comment: For blog posts you would use a set of Objects (e.g. `@objs = Obj.all`) and loop through them in your view: `@objs.each { |obj| .. }`. If you'd provide a more concrete example it would be easier to answer :]

Comment: @pex, that's not the problem. I want to keep my app DRY, and in a blog engine, you have to display messages in the blog itself, in user's page (list all his messages) and in many other places. That's why it's better to create a partial view "blog_message" and to call it every time you need to render a blog message. But with no controller initialization possible, you have to do necessary initialization in a view, and repeat it every time. For example, I want to show the Admin badge next to the post. I need to connect to a database and if a user is Admin, display an image next to his username.